# ruby - insert an array into initialize method - undefined method `join' for :String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, erb

I try to pass an array as argument and use it in my ERB file.

```
class Erbfile
  def initialize ec2
    @ec2 = ec2
    #@ec2 = ["Cleveland", "Denver", "Nashville"] #this one work
    @template = File.read('./file.erb')
  end
  def render
      ERB.new(@template).result( binding )
  end
end

ec2=[]
ec2.instances.each do |instance|
  tag_name = Facter::Util::Resolution.exec("...")
  mystring = "#{tag_name}"
  ec2 << mystring
  puts "#{ec2_without_tags}"        ### ["test.ec2.mycomany.int"]
  @page = Erbfile.new("#{ec2}")
end
```

I use in the ERB file:

```
<th> <%= @ec2.join('<br />') %> </th>
```

And i get an error:

```
(erb):20:in `render': undefined method `join' for "[\"test.ec2.mycomany.int\"]":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  JSON
```

but if I will insert an array manually into the initialize method, it will work.

```
@ec2 = ["Cleveland", "Denver", "Nashville"]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There is no [`String#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html) method, as the error says. The code is likely expecting an Array; the error shows a *string representation* of some kind of (JSON) array - fix that.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a string representation of your array into your Erbfile class. You then invoke `.join` on that string.

If you want to receive an array in your class, you need to *pass in* an array.

Replace  `Erbfile.new("#{ec2}")` with `Erbfile.new(ec2)`.

Comment: Worth noting that patterns like `"#{x}"` are almost always mistakes. Pass through that variable as-is. If you need to convert to a string: `x.to_s` instead.